# Cannot embed interop types from assembly "...\Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll" because it is missing the GuidAttribute attribute

Tags: dll, guid, attributes, visual-studio-2010

I get this error when adding a reference to the Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll library in a new project that I created.

Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll is a library that provides some useful API to communicate with Windows Search. I use it in order to add a folder to the system indexer.

Did anybody else get this error, and if so, how should I go about solving it?

I'm using VS2010 RC on a Windows Server 2008 if that is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I eventually figured it out. Apparently, there is a Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll file somewhere within the Windows Search SDK code examples.

You can get the code examples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssearch), and just use the windows search to find it.

Hope it helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

Go to the Properties window for Microsoft.Search.Interop and change the "Embed Interop Type" property to False.

Comment: You are assuming we don't want it embedded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I had done wrong is, I had marked "Embed Interop Type" property of referencing dll to True instead of marking for "Copy Local". The error went away when I reset "Embed Interop Type" to False, it all worked fine. Hope this helps somebody.Thanks!