# How to remove warning message in .net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

how to remove warning in.Net 2010

"Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Typess' property on either assembly."

Comment: Do you want to disable build warnings or what?

Comment: Please show us the code that triggers this warning.

Comment: To eliminate this warning, consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly.

Comment: @AndriyBuday yes its build warning..

Comment: Just removing a warning does not fix any problem. Please don't touch my code.

Comment: Hey I know waring does ot Fixed any problem.. i just need to remove all warning from my project..

Comment: Then set warning level to 0. This will not help your project and this way you will just fool your manager.

Answer (score 1):

**Usually** you don't need to disable build warnings. Best practice would be to have high level of warnings. If it happens that your project has some specifics you can navigate to `build properties` of your `csproj` and add `warning code` in `Suppress warnings:` section (warning code you are looking for is 1762).

**To fix your warning you should**:
Go to the Dll in the References, Right Click and go to Properites and change 'Embed Interop Types' property there.

**To completely disable warnings** in your project set warning level to 0. Not recommended!

Comment: Hey Andriy, Thank you so much for your answer.. But i need to remove all warnings in my project... My manager need zero warning in all project.. I dont understand why this warning is coming from..

Comment: To fix your warning you should: Go to the Dll in the References, Right Click and go to Properites and change 'Embed Interop Types' property there.

Comment: You should consider each warning you see, understand why it happens and only then fix or suppress :)

Comment: I did change the property but it give me another error. GuidAttribute missing.

Comment: If it produces errors then probably you need to suppress warning. But please find out why your project need that property to be set as it is now.

Comment: GuidAttribute is another question. :) Look for similar questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514813/cannot-embed-interop-types-from-assembly-microsoft-search-interop-dll-beca